# jQuery ajax (with rails): specify dataType at runtime

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails 3 app w/ jquery-ujs and I was wondering if its possible to dynamically specify the datatype of an ajax call at runtime. My links are all unobtrusive by binding the ajax events as such:

```
item.bind("ajax:beforeSend", function(e, request, settings) {
    ...
});
```

But unfortunately, the default dataType is json, and I was wondering if I could change this right before the ajax call. I know I can do this as such, on a per link basis:

```
<%= link_to('My Link', path,
        :remote => true,
        :method => :put,  
        :id => 'my-link',
        'data-type' => 'html', 
        :class => 'button') %>
```

But that isn't very DRY as I would have to do that on every link.

I found that I am able to set this field globally as such:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ dataType: 'html' });
```

But I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this inside the bind method, or on the item itself?

The only thing that comes to mind (as I write this), is adding the data-type attribute to the tag in JS, but I'm not sure if the ajax has already been setup by the time the JS executes.

Any ideas?

Comment: @ThiefMaster Most of my open questions don't have solid answers to them, hence the reason I haven't accepted them.

Answer (score 0):

for me, a quick and dirty way:   add the suffix to the url:

```
"#{link_to some_path}.html"
"#{link_to some_path}.js"
```